# How to define "is a structure" by a first-order formula of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

So, I've been trying to define a series of notions by first-order formulas in ZFC, and I'd like to know if I'm getting this right. In particular, I'd like to know if my formula for defining a first-order structure is correct. Generally, we understand, rather informally, a structure as, say, $\mathfrak{A} = \langle A, r_i, f_j, c_k \rangle_{i \in I, j \in J, k \in K}$, with each $r_i$, $f_j$, and $c_k$ being, respectively, a relation symbol, a function symbol, and a designated element, all indexed by the sets $I, J, K$. So in order to express this by a first-order, I came up with:

$\mathrm{Str}(\mathfrak{A}) = _{\text{def}} \exists A, I, J, K, R, F, C [(\forall r \in R (\mathrm{Rel}(r) \wedge \exists n \in \omega \mathrm{Dom}(r) = A^n \wedge \mathrm{Ran}(r) = A \wedge \exists \nu (\mathrm{Func}(\nu) \wedge \mathrm{Dom}(\nu)= I \wedge \mathrm{Ran}(\nu) = R \wedge \mathrm{Bij}(\nu))) \wedge (\forall f \in F (\mathrm{Func}(f) \wedge \exists n \mathrm{Dom}(f) = A^n \wedge \mathrm{Ran}(f) = A \wedge \exists \mu \mathrm{Dom}(\mu) = J \wedge \mathrm{Ran}(\mu) = F \wedge \mathrm{Bij}(\mu))) \wedge (\forall c \in C (c \in A \wedge \exists \xi \mathrm{Dom}(\xi) = K \wedge \mathrm{Ran}(\xi) = C \wedge \mathrm{Bij}(\xi)) \wedge (\mathfrak{A} = \langle A, R, F, C \rangle)]$

Assuming, of course, that the predicates "is a relation", "is a function", "is the domain of", "is the range of", "is a bijection", are already defined. Does that work? Is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: I am curious: what is the motivation behind your question?

Comment: @Jonny - Well, there are a couple. The immediate one is to help me solve a step in an exercise from Chang & Keisler, in which they ask us to formalize the satisfaction by a sequence relation in ZFC. Other than that, it was prompted by Peter Smith's remarks on Manzano's book *Model Theory*, according to which her definition of structure (which is pretty standard) is not very rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way, I think, is to use the following approach.

We have the language, $\cal L$ which is an ordered tuple of pairwise disjoint sets, and a function $\sigma$. The sets are constants, relations, functions and variable symbols. And you have an arity function $\sigma$ which takes a relation and function symbol and returns a natural numbers for the arity of that symbol.

An interpretation for $\cal L$, a structure, is a pair $(M,\Sigma)$ where $M$ is a non-empty set and $\Sigma$ is the interpretation function. Namely:

1. For every constant symbol $c$ in $\cal L$, $\Sigma(c)$ is an element of $M$.
2. For every relation symbol $R$ in $\cal L$, $\Sigma(R)\subseteq M^{\sigma(R)}$.
3. For every function symbols $f$ in $\cal L$, $\Sigma(f)\colon M^{\sigma(f)}\to M$.

Your suggestion seems to be somewhat close to this. But there are issues.
If $R$ is a binary relation symbol, it cannot be interpreted as a ternary relation symbol, but by saying $\exists n$ you in fact allow that. Additionally the domain or range of $R$ need not be everything.

If this is not what you meant, then it goes to show you that your suggestion is quite complex and unclear.

Finally, if you want a general notion of structure, then just state "There exists a language $\cal L$ such that $(M,\Sigma)$ is a $\cal L$-structure".

Comment: Yea, that's why I was asking for a simpler suggestion. Part of the problem is that I was trying to define a structure in general, in contrast to an $\mathscr{L}$-structure, which seems to be what your definition is getting at.

Comment: Well, "There exists a language $\cal L$ such that $(M,\Sigma)$ is an $\cal L$-structure".

Comment: Nice! Still, I was thinking more of definitions such as you find in universal algebra books (e.g. Mal'cev), which tend to bypass the reference to a language altogether. But I like that suggestion.

Comment: Asaf, since I'm trying to characterize a general notion of structure, without reference to a language, the problem of getting the right arity for my relations disappears, right? (If necessary, I can introduce arity functions later by characterizing the notion of a structure type) Also, the problem with the domain and range of $R$ can be solved by using subsets of $A$, instead of $A$ itself. Do you see other problems with my formula?

Comment: Yes, arity is not *that* of an issue if you don't care about the language. You just want to say that $R\subseteq M^n$ for some $n$, so you won't have some situation where different lengths of tuples sneak into the same relation. Functions have to have the domain as $M^n$ for some $n>0$, and codomain $M$.

Comment: Asaf, sorry to bother you one more time, but I was thinking about that arity function $\sigma$ from your answer. If I'm going to define a language $\mathcal{L}$ by a formula, do I need to include the definition of $\sigma$ in the formula? Or do I define it separately?

Comment: It's part of the definition, because without it you cannot form terms and formulas properly.

Comment: So the formula would be something like $\mathrm{Lang}(\mathcal{L}) =_{\text{def}} \dots \wedge \exists \sigma (\mathrm{Func}(\sigma) \wedge \mathrm{Dom}(\sigma) = (R \cup F) \wedge \mathrm{Rng}(\sigma) = \omega)$, where you put in the dots the formal definition of "is a tuple of pairwise disjoint sets etc."? Or something close to that?

Comment: Well, the range need not be $\omega$. What if you only have one binary relation? How can the artiy function have range $\omega$? But $\operatorname{Rng}(\sigma)\subseteq\omega$ is fine. As for the tuple, formally you can say that $\cal L$ is a language if it is a function with domain $4$, such that $\mathcal L(i)\cap\mathcal L(j)=\varnothing$ if and only if $i\neq j$, and that $\mathcal L(0)=R,\mathcal L(1)=F,\mathcal L(2)=C,\mathcal L(3)=V$. Of course this assumes that connectives and quantifiers lie in the logic, not in the language.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks!